# ¿Por qué me da error apt-get update?

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu

Instalé Lubuntu 16.04 en mi sistema y siempre que uso `sudo apt-get update` me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
W: El repositorio «cdrom://Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20170216) xenial Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: Los datos de un repositorio como este no se pueden autenticar y por tanto su uso es potencialmente peligroso.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
W: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: Los datos de un repositorio como este no se pueden autenticar y por tanto su uso es potencialmente peligroso.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: Fallo al obtener cdrom://Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20170216)/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages
Utilice «apt-cdrom» para hacer que APT reconozca este CD. No puede utilizar «apt-get update» para añadir nuevos CDs
E: Fallo al obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
```

He usado `apt-cdrom` como dice, pero no pasa nada. ¿Alguna idea de qué hago mal?

He tratado de instalar Node.js y también me muestra mensajes de error:

```
| > npm update check failed                                │
│           Try running with sudo or get access            │
│           to the local update config store via           │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/miguel/.config
```

Traté de limpiar la caché, pero no funcionó el comando `sudo npm cache clean -f`.

No sé qué más puedo hacer para corregir errores.

Comment: mira esto a ver si ayuda: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/324

Comment: para el primer error: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` buscas la línea que dice algo así como `deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Xenial Xerus` y le agregas un `# ` al principio así queda comentado y no trata de usar el cd como source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antiguamente, hasta hace unos 4 años, el repo de Chris Lea era la fuente para obtener versiones recientes de Node, pero desde el 2014, Chris Lea decidió [unir fuerzas con Nodesource](https://nodesource.com/blog/chris-lea-joins-forces-with-nodesource/), desde donde hoy se publican los paquetes oficiales.

En este momento tienes instalado un repo que dejó de publicar actualizaciones más o menos en la versión de Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) por lo tanto no hay un release para 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) ni una llave pública para éste. No te dejará instalar y el proceso de `sudo apt-get update` se verá interrumpido.

Vas a tener que quitar el repo que añadiste. Como primer paso, elimina los repos de tu carpeta `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chris-lea-node_js-*.list
```

Y correr luego

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Si eso no resulta, entonces primero corre:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y -r ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

Luego repite los pasos que te puse arriba.

Habiendo quitado el repo ofensivo (no es que sea un repo grosero, sólo que ensucia el procedimiento del apt update). Como decía, habiendo hecho esto, instala `nodejs` desde Nodesource. Por ejemplo la versión 8

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que a mi me funcionó fue cambiar el servidor al cual se conecta para verificar las actualizaciones:

1. Abrir aplicaciones y buscar "Software y Actualizaciones"
2. En donde dice "Descargar desde:" cambiar el servidor a "Servidor Principal"

Y listo, ahora debería conectarse al servidor principal y no al regional.